# VWP/B1 as foreign employee of a US company for meetings and getting to know the team

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

I'm a German citizen and currently waiting for my H1B application to come through. Now my employer, a US company, has asked me to come to the US for 2-3 weeks in August already, in order to get to know the team and hear more about the system I will be working on.

Their lawyers say I can do so under the Visa Waiver Program/B1 visa, but all information I can find say that I should not be employed by a US company/receive salary directly from them if I want to enter on the VWP/B1.

Other online sources however say that it's totally fine to go to the US on VWP/B1 for just a couple of meetings, so the more I read, the more I get confused. Can someone help me shed some light on this?

Comment: It may depend a bit on the company's legal structure.  Do they have any subsidiaries outside the US?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I can ask them if that makes any kind of difference.

Comment: If the company has a subsidiary outside the US, you should be able to receive wages or salary during the trip from the foreign subsidiary.  If they don't, I think you are correct that you should not attempt to use B-1 status or the VWP for this trip.  You might consider asking advice from an immigration lawyer, since the company's lawyers work for the company rather than for you.

Comment: I would contact the CBP (border control) Supervisor at the Airport where you intend to enter the US. No Immigration lawyer has a say in whether you get in or not, only the CBP at the specific Airport does

Comment: Where are you flying into? I'll give you the phone number to the CBP

Comment: That will probably be Philadelphia